EPPlus 7.3.2 Can't copy a worksheet from one workbook to another
I have looked everywhere for examples of how to copy a worksheet from one workbook to another.  They all seem to say use Workbook.Worksheets.Add(Name, SheetToCopy).
My code below does everything I want, but it fails on the Workbook.Worksheets.add(). My goal is to combine a folder fill of xlsx files, each with one or many tabs, into a single document.
The code below works just fine until I get to the Add.  Then I get a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error. If I don't pass the sheet object, then I get a file with all of the tabs created but no data.  It appears to be that it doesn't look at the sheet object as real.  I have confirmed it is real. After I create it, I am able to access any property from it.
Any thoughts on what I am missing here?
Thanks,
Scott
`using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Reflection.PortableExecutable;
//using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using OfficeOpenXml;

ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
string User = "Scott Smith"; 
//string srcFilePath = "C:\\Users\\" + User + "\\Documents\\Source\\";
//string tgtFilePath = "C:\\Users\\\" + User + \"\\Documents\\Target\\";
string resultFile = tgtFilePath + "TB 0624.xlsx";
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(srcFilePath, "*TB 062924.xlsx");

var newFile = new FileInfo(resultFile);
using ExcelPackage tgtPckg = new(newFile);
{
    Console.WriteLine(tgtPckg.File.Name);
    //tgtPckg.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Test");
    //tgtPckg.Save();
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(file);
        Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFileName(file));
        string location= Path.GetFileName(file).Substring(0, 5).Trim();
        using ExcelPackage srcPckg = new(new FileInfo(file));
        { 
            foreach (ExcelWorksheet sheet in srcPckg.Workbook.Worksheets)
            {
                //check name of worksheet, in case that worksheet with same name already exist exception will be thrown by EPPlus
                string workSheetName = sheet.Name;
                
                Console.WriteLine(workSheetName);

                        workSheetName = string.Format("{0}_{1}", location, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhssmmm"));
                Console.WriteLine(workSheetName);
                Console.WriteLine("Row Count: " + sheet.Rows.Count().ToString());
                //add new sheet
                var x = tgtPckg.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(workSheetName, sheet);
                x.View.SetTabSelected(false);
            }
        }
    }

    tgtPckg.SaveAs(new FileInfo(resultFile));
}`



I ran your code using some random xlsx files I had - and the only issue is duplicate worksheetnames, so I replaced your calculation of a worksheetname with a basic counter.  Before creating the target package
 int sheetNo = 1;

Then replace worksheetName assignment
workSheetName = $"{location}_{sheetCount:D3}";
sheetCount++;

It worked fine, and created an output xlsx file with all worksheets.
Targeting .NET 8.0 and using EPPlus 7.3.2

I really appreciate the response. I have logic for the duplicate worksheet names.  Just removed it to declutter the code.  I'm glad to know the code should work.  Now I just need to figure out what it doesn't work when I run it in VS on my machine.  Thanks again.
